# Is 테니스를 같이 칩시다 gramatically incorrect? In a sentence should the adverb only be placed before the object if there is one?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, word-order

Is object+adverb+verb an acceptable sentence structure in korean or should it be only adverb+object+verb as in the sentence : 테니스를 같이 칩시다

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both 테니스를 같이 칩시다 and 같이 테니스를 칩시다 are correct.
In actual spoken conversation, it is even possible to omit ~를 and say 테니스 같이 칩시다, or even 테니스 칩시다.